# Percentage in C Language

Tags: c, algorithm, percentage

i need some algorithm in language C to this:

```
0   ..... 100%
255 ..... 0%
50  ..... x%
```

How to find out how many will be x? I know only how to do this:

```
255 .... 100%
50  .... x%
```

And it solve this:

```
x = (50*100)/255;
```

Comment: Post your thoughts please. Otherwise this thread will be closed ´סּ︵סּ`

Comment: Look up [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
float percentage = 100.0 - (input*100/255);
```

The idea is to calculate the percentage over a range [0..255]. So, you divide whatever the number is by 255 and multiply by 100. But you want to invert the input, so that 0 is 100% and 255 is 0%. To get that, you subtract from 100.

Comment: Please don't provide a solution to question that doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding and shows no efforts.

Comment: @MarounMaroun There's nothing wrong with this question and the OP has very nearly found the answer him/herself.